# Meteor force-ssl behind aws LB

Tags: amazon-web-services, meteor

A Meteor app can be visited on http://example.com. It is in a docker container in a AWS EC2 behind an Application Load Balancer.

The visiter needs to see the green https in the url. Is it better to force a redirection to https on the Meteor app via force-ssl or via the Load Balancer or maybe some other AWS service? And if so, How?

Comment: Do you have a web server in front of it at all? like NGINX?

Comment: @TIC No, I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: Ok, I would definitely try to use the AWS ELB do the SSL termination. It will save your server resources and the AWS ELB actually does a really good job at SSL termination. That being said, I haven't done that before with a meteor app. Your app would still need to redirect all requests to HTTPS, but only listen on port 80. This is a short explanation: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-http-https-elb/.   Doing that with something like NGINX is easy, but I'm not sure on Meteor directly. I think using a web server in front could be helpful.

Comment: nginx or your load balancer can handle all the redirect to https. meteor doesn't need to run https

Comment: @Mikkel Could you show how it can be done with the Load Balancer?